# Check whether the data is between two numbers or not in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

This is the json where i should check condition

```
[
{
  "name" : "Rice",
  "mintemp" : "22",
  "maxtemp" : "32",
  "minrainfall" : "150",
  "maxrainfall" : "300",
  "soil" : ""
},
{
  "name" : "Wheat",
  "mintemp" : "10",
  "maxtemp" : "16",
  "minrainfall" : "75",
  "maxrainfall" : "100",
  "soil" : ""
},
{
  "name" : "Millets",
  "mintemp" : "27",
  "maxtemp" : "32",
  "minrainfall" : "50",
  "maxrainfall" : "100",
  "soil" : ""
},
{
  "name" : "Grams",
  "mintemp" : "20",
  "maxtemp" : "25",
  "minrainfall" : "40",
  "maxrainfall" : "45",
  "soil" : ""
},
{
  "name" : "Sugar Cane",
  "mintemp" : "21",
  "maxtemp" : "27",
  "minrainfall" : "75",
  "maxrainfall" : "150",
  "soil" : ""
},
{
  "name" : "Cotton",
  "mintemp" : "21",
  "maxtemp" : "30",
  "minrainfall" : "50",
  "maxrainfall" : "75",
  "soil" : ""
},
{
  "name" : "Coffee",
  "mintemp" : "15",
  "maxtemp" : "28",
  "minrainfall" : "150",
  "maxrainfall" : "250",
  "soil" : ""
}
]
```

Write a query to display all the name where mintemp should be between 16 to 20 and maxtemp also should be between  16 to 20

Expected Output :

```
[

{
  "name" : "Wheat",
  "mintemp" : "10",
  "maxtemp" : "16",
  "minrainfall" : "75",
  "maxrainfall" : "100",
  "soil" : ""
},
{
  "name" : "Grams",
  "mintemp" : "20",
  "maxtemp" : "25",
  "minrainfall" : "40",
  "maxrainfall" : "45",
  "soil" : ""
},
{
  "name" : "Coffee",
  "mintemp" : "15",
  "maxtemp" : "28",
  "minrainfall" : "150",
  "maxrainfall" : "250",
  "soil" : ""
}
]
```

Check it with mongoplayground.net and send the link

https://mongoplayground.net/p/jV0e00_FQ_P

above link contains the json and just type only query

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to mongoplayground.net :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

welcome to StackOverlow!

Please notice, that the JSON format does know the `integer` data type. Using the following JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Rice",
    "mintemp": 22,
    "maxtemp": 32,
    "minrainfall": 150,
    "maxrainfall": 300,
    "soil": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Wheat",
    "mintemp": 10,
    "maxtemp": 16,
    "minrainfall": 75,
    "maxrainfall": 100,
    "soil": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Millets",
    "mintemp": 27,
    "maxtemp": 32,
    "minrainfall": 50,
    "maxrainfall": 100,
    "soil": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Grams",
    "mintemp": 20,
    "maxtemp": 25,
    "minrainfall": 40,
    "maxrainfall": 45,
    "soil": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Sugar Cane",
    "mintemp": 21,
    "maxtemp": 27,
    "minrainfall": 75,
    "maxrainfall": 150,
    "soil": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Cotton",
    "mintemp": 21,
    "maxtemp": 30,
    "minrainfall": 50,
    "maxrainfall": 75,
    "soil": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Coffee",
    "mintemp": 15,
    "maxtemp": 28,
    "minrainfall": 150,
    "maxrainfall": 250,
    "soil": ""
  }
]
```

From here on, you can use the following solution to query your data for ranges:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      mintemp: {
        $gte: 16,
        $lte: 20
      }
    },
    {
      maxtemp: {
        $gte: 16,
        $lte: 20
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Please see my [solution proposal](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BcNtPGjpTIf).